# Where does Blazor authentication providers store JWT tokens?

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I'm creating a Blazor WASM SPA (that communicates with an API), with initial custom authentication and I'm trying to work out where to store the JWT token.

I know I can create a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider` implementation to retrieve the JWT token from the server. I know I can create a custom `IAccessTokenProvider` to provide the token for HTTP requests.  Where do I store the JWT inbetween?

Where do the other implementations store the JWT token?  Is there another class I can instantiate, or are they doing JS wrappers into local storage?

I can easily store the token in local storage, but there are different ideas on the web on where is secure, so I'd like to follow the existing provider implementations, but I can't find the sources to see how they do it.

Comment: It's a webapp. Use cookie authentication + [XSRF protection](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/asp-net-core-angular-xsrf-62c3833fd1fe) please

Comment: Unfortunately, Blazor isn't written with that in mind, it appears to be geared around "Authorization: Bearer" headers.  I want to follow the existing patterns. As your liked page says: "using Bearer authentication on the api controllers "